# where does gradle put the jars it downloads?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio with Gradle. Where in my project do I find the jar files that I am pulling with Gradle with say

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Digging through Android Studio I find a `xml` file under

```
/Users/myname/StudioProjects/Myproject/.idea/libraries/picasso_2_5_2.xml
```

I look inside, opened a terminal and routed to the path suggested. I get to the jar. Now I want to browse it. If I source for `picasso-2.5.2-sources.jar` using Spotlight Search then nothing is found. So obviously I cannot just get to it to view what's inside. So how might I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When running Gradle, a `.gradle` folder is created in your home directory: `~/.gradle/caches`.